# UIView added to a ScrollView and touchesDidBegin issue

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, uiscrollview, touchesbegan

Im adding a UIView as a subView to a scrollView. However, I wish to detect touches in the UIView. But i notice that when i do something like this:

```
[self.myScrollView addSubview:myView];
```

then, the touchesDidBegin method is never called when i touch the subview. However, if i do the following,

```
[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

then, the touchesDidBegin method is called. However, now the subView does not scroll along with the scroller obviously.

I want "myView" to be added to the scrollView as a subview so that it scrolls along with it and also detects touches on it. Any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Duplicate of the questions mentioned by Jhaliya below. [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241152/handling-touch-events-within-a-child-uiscrollview) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363598/touch-events-not-working-on-uiviews-inside-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same has already discussed here, plz find the link to similar SO post.

[Handling touch events within a child UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241152/handling-touch-events-within-a-child-uiscrollview)

[Touch events not working on UIViews inside UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363598/touch-events-not-working-on-uiviews-inside-)
uiscrollview